# Добавить условие в построитель запрсов

Tags: php

Подскажите, как добавить условие if в построитель запросов. Что-то вроде этого:

```html
$log = $Site->model('DB\Product')->getList([
    'where' => [
        'id' => $id,
        if($_GET['name']{
          ['name, '=', 'part'],
         }
    ],
    
    'orderBy' => [
        'ID' => 'DESC',
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сформируйте условие где-то ещё, например так:

```
$whereArr = ['id' => $id]

if ($_GET['name']) {
    $whereArr = array_merge($whereArr, ['name, '=', 'part']);
}

...
...
->getList([
    'where' => $whereArr,
])
```